# How to imitate a GET call to a REST API endpoint in Django Rest Framework from the browser with JSON Data

Tags: django, python-3.x, rest, api

I am trying to add numbers with a REST API created with Django Rest Framework. What I am trying to perform is that I make a GET call to the API and provide data in the form of JSON. The API then sends me sum of the numbers in JSON format.

This is the function based api view I have written to add the numbers.

```js
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
from rest_framework.response import Response
import json

# Create your views here.
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def api_add(request):
    sum = 0
    response_dict = {}
    if request.method == 'GET':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        for key in data:
            sum += data[key]
        response_dict = {"sum": sum}
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        # Do nothing
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        for key in data:
            sum += data[key]
        response_dict = {"sum": sum}
    
    
    return JsonResponse(json.loads(json.dumps(response_dict)), safe=False, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

The urls.py has the following.

```js
from django.urls import path
import Prediction.views as views

urlpatterns = [
    path('add/', views.api_add, name = 'api_add')
]
```

The urls.py is linked to main .urls.py as below:

```js
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('Prediction.urls')),
]
```

So basically my url is http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/add/.

I can make GET calls to the above API from Postman. Postman is able to perform both the GET and POST requests and is able to get a response back in JSON format.
[image]

However if I try to do the same in browser I get an error as below.

[image: RES]

How do I make the GET request from the browser with the JSON. Any help much appreciated